# Access a certain item of the IList<T> type

Tags: c#, list

I am trying to access a specific data from the IList.

```
public static void export(IList<T> data){
var test = data[1];
var x = test.day;
}
```

This is what I get as the value and type of var test:
[test value and type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLq1Z.png)

Even though the type is set to the type of my model the code sees it as T.
How can I access the "day" value?

This is my first post so sorry if something is out of order, thanks in advance.

Kind regards.

Comment: In future, please use the built-in functionality to add an image, so it displays inline with the question, rather than linking to an imgur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How do you know that `T` actually has a `day` property? `T` could be anything. If you are expecting the list to contain all `workingHoursDbXls` objects, then I would suggest not making this method generic:

```
public static void export(IList<workingHoursDbXls> data)
{
    var test = data[1];
    var x = test.day;
}
```

Alternatively, you could specify some constraint, to say that you don't care what type `T` is, as long as it has a `day` property:

```
public interface IHaveADay
{
    string day { get; }
}

public static void export<T>(IList<T> data) where T : IHaveADay
{
    var test = data[1];
    var x = test.day;
}
```

You'll then need to update the declaration of your `workingHoursDbXls` class, to say that it implements `IHaveADay`:

```
public class workingHoursDbXls : IHaveADay
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Good answer, although it should be mentioned that for the second approach to work, the class `workingHoursDbXls` has to be changed to something like `class workingHoursDbXls : IHaveADay`.

Answer (score -1):

If you access the `day` property, the method will only work with objects that have that property, and only if you constrain T to an interface that exposes it.

```
public static void export<T>(IList<T> data) where T: workingHoursDbXls
{
    var test = data[1];
    var x = test.day;
}
```

Comment: Not the down voter, but there's nothing to constrain here (and it won't compile). Based on the definition `export` isn't generic in `T` (but perhaps the class is, in which case the constraint would go there) . Unless OP mistyped `export<T>(..)` as `export(...)` in which case you've copied the error.